# The symbol 'new' in C#, what is its use?

Tags: c#, new-operator

I have come across a problem upon viewing some tutorials on C# since I just started learning this language recently. I had a problem where once I had reversed a string I had to make use of new string in order to store its actual value in a different varible.

Why is the use of 'new string()' needed? In different programming languages I have never come across the need of using 'new string()'. Thanks in advance :)

//C#

```
char[] reversedName = name.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(reversedName); 
string result = new string(reversedName);
```

Comment: Its use is documented in the [language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator)

Comment: which "different languages" you refer to?  Knowing this it may be easier for us to explain to you the differences.

Comment: Different languages have different rules, semantics, syntax and constructs. You can seldom base your learning of a new language on another different language.

Comment: And just about all decent books and tutorials should have included chapters or sections about how to create objects, which would include the `new` keyword. So either the tutorial you're following is bad, or you skipped some part.

Comment: I made use of C and Java

Comment: Java have `new`, used in exactly the same way. The equivalent line in Java would be something like `String result = new String(reversedName);`.

Comment: I agree but I never made use of 'new' because without it's use everything performed just right that's why I was confused. So basically making the use of 'new' when creating a new object is always the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String` is a class like other classes in any Object oriented programming language and we can create object of it using `new` keyword like we would do for creating object of any type.

In your specific scenario above you have a `char` array and `String` class have a constructor overload which take `char[]` as input and create a `String`. So you call the constructor using `new String`.

So what is happening is you said to create an object of type string using `char[]` which is provided in the constructor of it.

Comment: Understood but what I don't understand is why would you need to create a new object in this case string, why wouldn't it store its actual value right away? Sorry if I am not explaining my question clearly.

Comment: @Evilc strings are immutable. You can't modify a string, you can only create a new string. Note also that `reversedName` is a different object in memory to `name` - you are creating an array based on the characters in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can - as in any other of your mentioned languages - of course also use something like this:

```
string m = "Hello World".
```

However your `reversedName` is **an array of `char`**, which is not convertible to `string` as is. So the following won´t work:

```
string myString = "Hello World".ToCharArray();
```

because `ToCharArray` - as the name suggests - returns `char[]`, not `string` and there´s no conversion between the two.

That´s why you need to create a new string using the [constructor that accepts an array of char](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_String__ctor_System_Char___).

Answer (score 0):

The `new`-Keyword is used to create a new instance of your class.

If you want to assign one value of one type to another type you have to convert it in some way.

There are multiple ways:

1. Call a Constructor which accepts your input (You did this, because there is a constructor for `string` which accepts `char[]`)
2. Use a Cast (No Cast available from `char[]` to `string`)
3. Use a Convert-Method (No available for converting values to `string` as far a I know)

Here an example-class which implements explicit and implicit casts (Which `System.String` does not):

```cs
class MyString
{
    private string stringValues;

    // Constructors
    public MyString(char[] charArray) { stringValues = new string(charArray); }
    public MyString(string str) { stringValues = str; }
    public MyString() { }

    // ToString for writing to console
    public override string ToString() { return stringValues; }

    // Operator to concat "MyStrings"
    public static MyString operator +(MyString a, MyString b) { return new MyString(a.ToString() + a.ToString()); }

    // Implicit Cast-operator string to MyString
    public static implicit operator MyString(string str) { return new MyString(str); }

    // Explicit Cast-operator char-array to MyString
    public static explicit operator MyString(char[] str) { return new MyString(str); }
}

internal static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyString tmp = new MyString("Initialize by constructor with parameter string");
    Console.WriteLine(tmp);

    tmp = new MyString("Initialize by constructor with parameter char-array".ToCharArray());
    Console.WriteLine(tmp);

    tmp = new MyString("x") + new MyString("+") + new MyString("y");
    Console.WriteLine("Use of '+ operator'" + tmp);

    tmp = "Initialize by creating string and using implicit cast for strings";
    Console.WriteLine(tmp);

    tmp = (MyString)("Initialize by creating char-array and using explicit cast for strings".ToCharArray());
    Console.WriteLine(tmp);
}
```